# Filter out specific objects of Iterable list by specific property

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Iterable list that I am sorting by for different values. I want to add a new filter for users to filter out the list to just show a specific property the list contains. I am trying to use `.where`, but it does not seem to be working and I am not sure what to do. I have searched the web and see many examples on how to filter out just a plain list for a specific value in the objects with comparable but not able to get this to where for an Iterable list.

Here is what I am trying and not getting any results I would expect.

```
case 'specificValue':
    return sorted.where((t) => t.state == 'speficicValue').toList();
```

Not sure if `.where` is the right way to filter out an Iterable list by a specific value within the objects of the list.

Comment: its right way but you need to store result of filter somewhere like  var sorted = _list.where((e) => e.name =='test').toList();  
now this sorted will print proper value

Comment: @AdamGardner why do you think `where` is not working? for example: `final f = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
print(f);
print(f.where((i) => i.isOdd));`

Comment: where is working but  you have to store result somewhere

Comment: @HardikMehta you dont have to "store" it anywhere, see my example above - i just pass it to `print` function

Comment: please refer this : https://ibb.co/MRTZ05N  you are just printing those that output need to be store somewhere

Comment: @pskink It is working. I am very new to Flutter and just looking at the UI on device it looked to be wrong. Once I say your code to print the list it showed me it was working as expected. So thank you for showing me how to log in Flutter, I kept trying to console.log() and that was not working but print() did.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with my new experience to Flutter and not knowing how too print. The list being filtered with `.where` was working but the list was so large it was hard to make sure it was showing up how I wanted. So printing it to the terminal I was able to look at the objects easier to validate the list was being filtered as I expected.